# Bazel for Mac os Lion

Tags: compiler-errors, osx-lion, bazel, developer-tools

Is there any bazel version compatible with Mac os Lion? I had try even the preview release until the 0.1.0 but always I get this error on me terminal `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: I would suggest you to give `bazelisk` a try? Do you get the same error?

Comment: Is a Docker container that runs Bazel an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Bazel does not work with Mac OSX Lion. Your best bet would be load Bazel in a Docker container.